# ServiceStack Secure cookie when HTTPS is terminated on the load balancer

Tags: servicestack

In ServiceStack, the `HostConfig` flag `UseSecureCookies = true` will mark cookies as Secure when transmitted over HTTPS.

However, in the real world, it is common to have SSL terminated at the load balancer, and then use HTTP on the inside (i.e. `Internet --https--> LB --http--> application`)

How can I achieve secure HTTPS cookies in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Secure cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_cookie) can only be transmitted over HTTPS, ServiceStack will still emit Secure Cookies behind a SSL terminated proxy, provided it correctly sets the `X-Forwarded-Proto: https` downstream HTTP Header.

E.g. here's a typical example of a [SSL Terminated nginx reverse proxy](https://docs.servicestack.net/deploy-netcore-to-amazon-linux-2-ami#etcnginxconfdmy-apporgconf):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name my-app.org;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort off;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        client_max_body_size 500m;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! It was a hassle to get IIS to add the header, but the URL Rewrite 2.0 module worked once I found that setting a server variable with a special syntax `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` _and_ adding it to the allowed server variables list (in the rewrite module) was how to do it.